# How to pass object to process output event

Tags: wpf, events, data-binding, event-handling, win32-process

I have an `ObservableCollection<Conversion>` Queue, bound to `ListBox` control with `ItemTemplate` containing a `TextBlock` and a `Button`. When the button is clicked, a Win32 process starts. This process has an `ErrorDataReceived` event handler method which reads the process output and is supposed to update the PercentComplete property of the `Conversion` object in the collection. PercentComplete is bound to `TextBlock`'s Text property.

How do I update PercentComplete from Win32 process event? I was hoping to pass the `Conversion` object to the `ErrorDataReceived` event handler, but the `DataReceivedEventArgs` only has a single Data property of type string.

Here is the code:

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Queue}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PercentComplete}" />
            <Button Command="convertor:Commands.RunConversion">Run</Button>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code-behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<Conversion> _queue;
public ObservableCollection<Conversion> Queue
{
   get { return _queue; }
   set
   {
      _queue = value;
      RaisePropertyChange("Queue");
   }
}

private Conversion _selectedItem;
public Conversion SelectedItem
{
   get { return _selectedItem; }
   set
   {
      _selectedItem = value;
      RaisePropertyChange("SelectedItem");
   }
}

private void RunConversion_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
   using (var ffmpeg = new Process())
   {
      ...
      ffmpeg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
      ffmpeg.ErrorDataReceived += FfmpegProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
      // I realize it is weird I am working with ErrorDataReceived instead 
      // of OutputDataReceived event, but that's how ffmpeg.exe rolls.
      ffmpeg.Start();
      ffmpeg.BeginErrorReadLine();
   }
}

private void FfmpegProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   var processOutput = e.Data;
   var percentComplete = ParsePercentComplete(processOutput);

   //TODO Pass percentComplete to Conversion.PercentComplete!?
}
```

Class:

```
public class Conversion : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private double _percentComplete;
   public double PercentComplete
   {
      get { return _percentComplete; }
      set
      {
         _percentComplete = value;
         RaisePropertyChange("PercentComplete");
      }
   }

   public void RaisePropertyChange(string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. The key to the solution was the `process.Id` which provides the reference to the process specific to the `ObservableCollection` item.

Specifically, I expanded the `Conversion` with `Process` Process property to store the information of that particular process, and then I can find the item in the collection and update its properties from process output in process' event handler.

Here is the updated code:

Code-behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<Conversion> _queue;
public ObservableCollection<Conversion> Queue
{
   get { return _queue; }
   set
   {
      _queue = value;
      RaisePropertyChange("Queue");
   }
}

private Conversion _selectedItem;
public Conversion SelectedItem
{
   get { return _selectedItem; }
   set
   {
      _selectedItem = value;
      RaisePropertyChange("SelectedItem");
   }
}

private void RunConversion_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ...
   var ffmpeg = new Process();
   ffmpeg.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
   ffmpeg.ErrorDataReceived += FfmpegProcess_ErrorDataReceived;
   ffmpeg.Start();

   conversion.Process = ffmpeg; // This is new

   ffmpeg.BeginErrorReadLine();
}

private void FfmpegProcess_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   var processOutput = e.Data;
   var percentComplete = ParsePercentComplete(processOutput);

   var processId = (sender as Process).Id; // These three lines are new
   var conversion = Queue.Where(c => c.Process.Id == processId).FirstOrDefault();
   conversion.PercentComplete = percentComplete; // WTF!!!!
}
```

Class

```
public class Conversion : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private double _percentComplete;
   public double PercentComplete
   {
      get { return _percentComplete; }
      set
      {
         _percentComplete = value;
         RaisePropertyChange("PercentComplete");
      }
   }
   
   // New property
   private Process _process;
   public Process Process
   {
      get { return _process; }
      set
      {
         _process= value;
         RaisePropertyChange("Process");
      }
   }
   
   public void RaisePropertyChange(string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```